# Restart button doesn't work on Unity 5.6

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a restart button on top of a game over screen. But it seems that the button doesn't work. I've put it on the `On Click()` menu and it kept doing nothing when i clicked on it.
My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonCodes:MonoBehaviour
{
    public void RestartGame()
    {
       SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add this scene into build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for answering. All of the things that you said is already been done and still, the button won't work. In the end, i solved the problem myself. I realized that my Canvas doesn't have an `EventSystem` that was an important thing for a button to work.

Comment: EventSystem is created by default when you make a new Canvas in Unity, it is required for UI to function.

In future you might want to include more information, such as "My current UI does/doesn't work", or a screenshot/description of your scene hierarchy.

Comment: Okay, i'll try that next time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Look into 4.6 UI Buttons.

Create the button in your scene, and in OnClick, drag the gameObject with your `ButtonCodes` into the target field (left), and choose `RestartGame` in the right, which will be an option under `ButtonCodes`.

This might be what you've already done.. if that's the case, try using some `Debug.Log("Button was Clicked");` statements. If these show up, it's likely you haven't set up the Build settings to include any levels. (Unity does not add levels here just by pressing play - you must do this yourself)

Answer (score 1):

Assumming there are no errors, the most likely reason it's not working is that you didn't specify any scenes in File/Build Settings (Ctrl+Shift+B)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

That shows that you need to order your scenes in the Build Settings if you use the sceneBuildIndex. You could also use the second LoadScene that uses sceneName which may be more reliable if you constantly reorder scenes in Build Settings.

Also, if you haven't already, try using Debug.Log to make sure that that part of the code is actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the name of the scene in the scenemanager and make sure your scene you gonna load is on your build settings

```
 public void RestartGame()
{
   SceneManager.LoadScene(//name of your scene);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Sometimes when i duplicate a button and use it with other functions, it doesn't work.

2- Another reason that i faced was when i use inherited class, it doesn't work many times too.

3- Sometimes you forget to add your "0" scene in to build setting as well.